# How to enable OutputCache with an IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `IHttpHandler` that I would like to hook into the OutputCache support so I can offload cached data to the IIS kernel. I know MVC must do this somehow, I found this in `OutputCacheAttribute`:

```
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        // we need to call ProcessRequest() since there's no other way to set the Page.Response intrinsic
        OutputCachedPage page = new OutputCachedPage(_cacheSettings);
        page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }

    private sealed class OutputCachedPage : Page {
        private OutputCacheParameters _cacheSettings;

        public OutputCachedPage(OutputCacheParameters cacheSettings) {
            // Tracing requires Page IDs to be unique.
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _cacheSettings = cacheSettings;
        }

        protected override void FrameworkInitialize() {
            // when you put the <%@ OutputCache %> directive on a page, the generated code calls InitOutputCache() from here
            base.FrameworkInitialize();
            InitOutputCache(_cacheSettings);
        }
    }
```

But not sure how to apply this to an `IHttpHandler`. Tried something like this, but of course this doesn't work:

```
public class CacheTest : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        OutputCacheParameters p = new OutputCacheParameters { Duration = 3600, Enabled = true, VaryByParam = "none", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server };
        OutputCachedPage page = new OutputCachedPage(p);
        page.ProcessRequest(context);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        context.Response.End();

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be done like this:

```
public class CacheTest : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        TimeSpan expire = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(now.Add(expire));
        context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(expire);
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
        context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you try this and refresh the page you will see a new time with each refresh.

Comment: Sorry, take out the Response.End

Comment: This still is missing the IIS Kernel Cache (checking via perfmon.msc Web Service Cache\Kernel: URI Cache Misses, Web Service Cache\Kernel: URI Cache Hits)